# Prevent typed input from scrolling with cout

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, scroll, cout

I've noticed that in many well-written terminal applications, typed input will not scroll with output to the terminal.

For example, if `abc` is typed while `XXX\nXXX\n` is output to the terminal, it will most likely look something like this:

```
a
XXX
XXX
bc
```

In this example, how can the `abc` be kept at the bottom of the terminal while the output to the terminal, `XXX\nXXX\n`, scrolls above it?

How can my intent be implemented?

Comment: This cannot be done with just standard c++, you need to make use of your terminal capabilities, which is easier if you use a library like ncurses. At any rate, this is platform dependent, so you will need to add that to the question.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Sorry about that!  I added the linux tag.  Will look into ncurses!  Thank you!